# O-Notation Prove or Disprove $ 3^{O(n)} = O(8^{n})$

Tags: asymptotics

I am really new in data algorithm and Big O-Notation and could not find a good solution for this:

$$ 3^{O(n)} = O(8^{n}) $$

First of all what does this term $ 3^{O(n)}$ mean?

I thought using the definition of O-Notation: $f(n) \leq c g(n)$. But this does not apply if $O(n)$ are on the both side or?

Comment: $2n=O(n)$ but $3^{2n}=9^n$ is ...

Answer (score 1):

We can only make sence of the claim
$$ 3^{O(n)}=O(8^n)$$
as meaning

> If $f(n)\in O(n)$, then $3^{f(n)}\in O(8^n)$.

But with this interretation, the claim is false: Consider $f(n)=2n$ and show that $9^n\notin O(8^n)$.

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick reply and does this mean i consider the term 3 O(n) just as f(n) and think a claim to prove this?

Comment: S/he just argued that you cannot prove this.